# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable after running an import-script

Tags: php, plesk, http-status-code-503, plesk-onyx

I have a domain on a Plesk server (version 17.8) with CentOS 7. Prestashop is installed on this domain and the products are imported via a self-programmed module.
When I start import then I get the message:
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is unable to service your request due to downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Web Server at sportsams.ch

In the log I get this message: (70007) The timeout has been specified: AH01075: Error dispatching request to:

```
PHP setting for the domain:
PHP version: 7.2.18 with FPM
Memory_limit: 256M
max_execution_time: 1000
max_input_time: 1000
post_max_size: 16M
upload_max_filesize:16M
```

The support of Plesk told me that this must make adjustments:

1. Plesk> domains> sportsams.ch> Apache & nginx Settings.
2. Additional directives for HTTP and Additional directives for HTTPS:

   ```
   FcgidIdleTimeout 1200
   FcgidProcessLifeTime 1200
   FcgidConnectTimeout 1200
   FcgidIOTimeout 1200
   Timeout 1200
   ProxyTimeout 120
   ```
3. Click OK button to apply the changes

Unfortunately, these settings have not been successful.

I hope someone else can give me an idea.

If you need more information, let me know.

```
Centos 7 Server with Plesk 17.8.
PHP-Version 7.2.18 With FPM
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your Plesk configuration, but I've been using the following configuration to set the timeout correctly with PrestaShop & Nginx:

```
location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/var/www/myshop.com/:/tmp/";
}
```

If `fastcgi_read_timeout` does not work for you, it might be related to a hosting provider limitation detecting you are consuming too much resources.

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry that I ask so, can you tell me exactly where do you added this configuration? Then I can try it too, maybe that's the solution.

Comment: Sure, in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myshop.com however I guess the location is different when you use Plesk

Comment: i found the file in this folder: /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/sportsams.ch.conf
i have added this lines and modify the last line with the correct path of the shop. 
should i restart a service or is that not necessary?

Comment: You can perform a soft reload (`systemctl reload nginx`) that will reload the configuration.

Comment: Hi
After I made the settings, I started the script again. Unfortunately, the same mistake came again.

Comment: I'd be happy to have a look with you, please ping me in the official PrestaShop Stack Overflow chat room (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192800/prestashop)